# Why is DateTime.UtcNow showing 4 hours behind instead of 8 hours ahead of PST time?

Tags: c#, .net

Why is DateTime.UtcNow showing 4 hours behind instead of 8 hours ahead of PST time?

```
Console.WriteLine("UtcNow: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Now (Pacific Time): " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

**Output**

UtcNow: 2/6/2023 8:17:50 PM

Now (Pacific Time): 2/6/2023 12:17:50 PM

Comment: Because the 12-hour clock is weird, that's why sane people will always prefer the 24-hour clock (and `yyyy-MM-dd` as the only acceptable date format). Timekeeping is complex enough without the arbitrary stuff we've piled on top of it...

Answer (score 1):

12:00 PM is noon. 12:00 AM is midnight. 8:17 PM is eight hours after 12:17 PM.

Comment: Long live 24h time.

Comment: Of course. Thanks! What I really want is 24 hour UTC time.

Comment: Look at the overloads of DateTime.ToString for custom date formatting.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings